# The implementation of functional "Levels" like in Photoshop

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, photoshop

Faced with such a problem. Need to implement the ability to corrections for Levels, as in Photoshop:

[image: http://www.atpm.com/13.04/images/photoshop-05-levels.png]

The problem is this: there are all the data for each pixel of image, there is data entered by the user InputWhite, InputBlack, OutputWhite, OutputBlack. (as shown in the figure).

I need to change every 3 channel specifically for each pixel (RGB).

How Can I change their ? I can not understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your image link is truncated.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you need help with. Do you need help manipulating pixels in a HTML `<canvas>`? Or do you need someone to tell you the algorithm used by Photoshop? (The latter would make this a not very good SO question.)

Comment: output white means to turn anything above it to 255, anything under output black becomes 0, easy enough. input is harder, and you don't mention a mid tone balancer. with input, you scale 0-255 to inpWhite - inpBlack. then for each pixel, if under 128, multiply the pixel level by the scale. if over 128, multiply by 1/scale. finally,  min(255,p) and max(0, p) for safety.

Comment: It would be good to know exactly algorithm.I need to include this functionality in my program, but I can not. But all the actions I have made ​​on the canvas, but I think it's not so important.

Comment: @GeraySuinov Take a look at how histograms works: http://www.luminous-landscape.com/tutorials/understanding-series/understanding-histograms.shtml and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_histogram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `imageData` of the canvas to modify the RGB values of individual pixels however you please.

For instance to "increase" the green "channel" of all pixels you could do this, which adds 30 to the value of each G in the RGB of every pixel:

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,can.width, can.height);
var pixels = imageData.data;
var numPixels = pixels.length;

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

for (var i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
    var average = (pixels[i*4] + pixels[i*4+1] + pixels[i*4+2]) /3;
    // set red green and blue pixels to the average value
    pixels[i*4] = 0;
    pixels[i*4+1] += 30;
    pixels[i*4+2] += 0;
}
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YxYuF/

From there it's just a question of making a nice UI to present to the user.

Comment: It's not quite what I need. I can change the values​​. But by what algorithm does not know?